# Cakephp, beforeUpload() function is overwriting using miles johnson Uploader

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, plugins

First, thanks for Miles Johnson for make a great plugin for upload on cakephp
But I have some problem
I want to set uploaddir in my model with beforeupload() function
but it wasnt adding array's data in my attachment
its overwriting all my attachment uploader configuration
this is my model

```
class File extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
                'fileupload' => array(
                     'maxNameLength'    => 255,
                     'overwrite'    => true,
                     'stopSave'    => true,
                     'allowEmpty'    => false,
                     'dbColumn' => 'path_file',
                     'prepend' => '',
                     'uploadDir' => '',
                     'finalPath' =>''
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeUpload()
    {
    $folderid = $this->data['File']['folder_id'];
    foreach($this->folder_path($folderid) as $row)
    {
        $folder = trim($row[0]['folder']);
        $subfolder = trim($row[0]['subfolder']);
    }
$options['prepend'] = Configure::read('dept_sess') . Configure::read('timeunique')."==";
$options['uploadDir'] = 'files/' . Configure::read('dept_sess') . '/' .$folder. '/' .$subfolder. "/";
        return $options;
        }
    }
```

Assume my controller and $this->folder_path is right,
when I executed save() on my controller
it was give an error
debug result of $attachment

```
array(
    'prepend' => '0000010820131030174740==',
    'uploadDir' => 'files/00000108/folder/subfolder/'
)
```

my $attachment configuration was overwritted,and not add the data of attachment array.
why my beforeUpload() function cannot add data on attachment array?
for worst solution I just add all attachment data on beforeupload() like :

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
                'fileupload' => array()));

    public function beforeUpload()
    {
    $folderid = $this->data['File']['folder_id'];
    foreach($this->folder_path($folderid) as $row)
    {
        $folder = trim($row[0]['folder']);
        $subfolder = trim($row[0]['subfolder']);
    }
    $options['name'] = Configure::read('dept_sess') . Configure::read('timeunique')."==";
    $options['baseDir'] = 'files/' . Configure::read('dept_sess') . '/' .$folder. '/' .$subfolder. "/";
    $options['uploadDir'] = 'files/' . Configure::read('dept_sess') . '/' .$folder. '/' .$subfolder. "/";
    $options['append'] = '';
    $options['overwrite '] = false;
    $options['prepend'] = Configure::read('dept_sess') . Configure::read('timeunique')."==";
    $options['dbColumn'] = 'file_path';
    $options['importFrom'] = '';
    $options['defaultPath'] = '';
    $options['maxNameLength'] = '';
    $options['stopSave'] = '';
    $options['allowEmpty'] = false;
    $options['saveAsFilename'] = '';
    $options['transforms'] = '';
    $options['s3']['host'] = '*****';
    $options['s3']['format'] = 'http://{host}/{bucket}/{path}';
    $options['s3']['accessKey'] = '';
    $options['s3']['secretKey'] = '';
    $options['s3']['ssl'] = '';
    $options['s3']['bucket'] = '';
    $options['s3']['path'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['ext'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['type'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['size'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['group'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['width'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['height'] = '';
    $options['metaColumns']['filesize'] = '';
    $options['finalPath'] = '';
    $options['field'] = '';
    return $options;
    }
```

I want to avoid this way for my code, anyone can give solution?
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to receive `$options` in your `beforeUpload()` so you can then modify it. Since you're not doing it, you're just creating a new array with only the options you set in your function.

```
public function beforeUpload($options)
{
    $folderid = $this->data['File']['folder_id'];
    foreach($this->folder_path($folderid) as $row) {
        $folder = trim($row[0]['folder']);
        $subfolder = trim($row[0]['subfolder']);
    }
    $options['prepend'] = Configure::read('dept_sess') . Configure::read('timeunique')."==";
    $options['uploadDir'] = 'files/' . Configure::read('dept_sess') . '/' .$folder. '/' .$subfolder. "/";
    return $options;
}
```

You can see that the `$options` is passed to it here https://github.com/milesj/uploader/blob/master/Model/Behavior/AttachmentBehavior.php#L516

Comment: Oh god, I forgot to put $option
thx for reminding..
this was silly question, Im sorry :D